# Custom \maketitle in my custom class not working when I use report class

Tags: titles, documentclass-writing

I am trying to write a new class using the report class. In my custom class I have used a custom `\maketitle`. But it is not working. But it works, if I use `article` class as my base. My class file is

```
\ProvidesClass{mins}[2/8/2013]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption*{\InputIfFileExists{\CurrentOption.min}{}{
\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}}

\ProcessOptions \relax

\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%[left=.5in,right=.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in]
\RequirePackage[top=.5in,bottom=.5in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}


\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
Hello World
  }


\newcommand{\makeack}{
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
Hello World Again
}
```

and my TeX file is

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\title{My report Title}
\author{My Name}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\makeack

\end{document}
```

My output is [image]

When I replace `article` with `report` in the class file, the output changes to

[image]

Comment: What does "not working" mean when using `report`? What does "it works" mean when using `article`? What kind of error message(s) do you get?

Comment: In addition to Werner's questions, which is the *actual* definition of `\@maketitle`?

Comment: @Werner When `report` is used normal title comes. When `article` is used, my custom title comes.

Comment: Hard to provide help if you don't provide the information that has been requested. Please, let us see your *actual* definition of `\@maketitle` and a *complete*, *minimal* example document showing the problem.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am a beginner. actual definition means?

Comment: @user3984 the actual code; you surely didn't use `\def\@maketitle{
....
...
}`, the dots are place-holders, right? Please provide the code used, no just the place-holders.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I made changes to the question as you suggested

Comment: `report` by default has the `titlepage` option, in which case `\maketitle` doesn't use `\@maketitle`, so redefining it does nothing.

Comment: @egreg So in that case, what should I do?

Comment: @user3984 `\PassOptionsToClass{notitlepage}{report}`, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\PassOptionsToClass{notitlepage}{report}
```

in the class will help to solve that problem. Thanks @[egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) for the answer.